# What is the difference between a public nested class and private nested class in C#

Tags: c#, inner-classes

In C#, what, if any, differences are there between a public nested class and private nested class? When would you use one verses the other?

As far as I can tell they have the same accessibility from the view of the class they are nested in as well as from any external classes.

```
void Main()
{
    Item i = new Item();
    i.DoSomething();

    GizmoBuilder gb = new GizmoBuilder();//class not accessible
    WidgetBuilder wb = new WidgetBuilder();//class not accessible
}

public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    private string ItemName { get; set;}

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        GizmoBuilder g = new GizmoBuilder();
        g.BuildGizmo();
        Console.WriteLine(g.BuildId);
        Console.WriteLine(g.Name);//g.Name not accessible

        WidgetBuilder w = new WidgetBuilder();
        w.BuildWidget();
        Console.WriteLine(w.BuildId);
        Console.WriteLine(w.Name);//g.Name not accessible
    }

    public class GizmoBuilder
    {
        public int BuildId { get; set; }

        private string Name { get; set;}

        public void BuildGizmo()
        {           
            Builder b = new Builder();
            b.Build();

            Console.WriteLine("Building Gizmo");
        }
    }

    private class WidgetBuilder
    {
        public int BuildId { get; set; }

        private string Name { get; set;}

        public void BuildWidget()
        {
            Builder b = new Builder();
            b.Build();

            Console.WriteLine("Building Widget");
        }
    }

    private class Builder
    {
        public void Build()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Building");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you stated the *correct* error message, the issue would be apparent.  The error is not telling you that the type is not accessible, as you claim; it's telling you that the type *doesn't exist at all*.  If the problem was merely that it wasn't accessible, it would *tell you that the type isn't accessible*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A simplified example:

```
public class Foo
{
    public class Bar { }

    private class Baz { }
}
```

Using them:

```
var bar = new Bar();
var nestedBar = new Foo.Bar();
var nestedBaz = new Foo.Baz();
```

At `GizmoBuilder gb = new GizmoBuilder()` you claim the "class [is] not accessible", but that's incorrect. The actual compiler error, belonging to the first line from the three above, is:

> CS0246: The type or namespace name `Bar' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?

That's because you have to prefix the containing class's name, as shown in the second line. That just works, because `Foo.Bar` is public.

The third line, accessing a private nested class, shows:

> CS0122: `Foo.Baz' is inaccessible due to its protection level

So there's your difference. You can only use the latter (`Foo.Baz`) from inside `Foo`.

Comment: My obliviousness about nested classes seems to be the answer to the question. I was unaware that you had to prefix the class with enclosing class to be able to "see" it.

Answer (score 3):

> As far as I can tell they have the same accessibility from the view of the class they are nested in as well as from any external classes.

From the class they are nested in, that is true however, if the nested class is private, no external class has access to it.

Answer (score 2):

If the nested class is public then you can instantiate it from *anywhere* with access to the enclosing class.

If the nested class is private, you can only instantiate it from the enclosing class.

This is useful when you need the enclosing class to be the *only* class that can create that new type.  For instance:

```
public interface INestedClass 
{
    double ComplexCalculation(double input);
}

public class Test 
{
    public INestedClass GenerateInstance() 
    {
        return new SubClass();
    }

    private class SubClass : INestedClass
    {
        public double ComplexCalculation(double input) 
        {
            return input*5;
        }
    }
}
```

From outside of the scope of the enclosed class, you wouldn't be able to do this because the nested class is private:

```
var subClassInstance = new Test.SubClass();
```

Answer (score 1):

This won't compile. That's the difference.

```
public class C {
    private class D {  }

    //  Nobody outside C can know about D, so this is forbidden. 
    public D Property { get; set; }

    //  But this is OK, because object is public. 
    private D _d = new D();
    public Object Property2 => _d;
}
```

Passing an instance of a private class to `Console.WriteLine()` has nothing to do with access; it sees a reference to `object` (public) and calls `ToString()` (public) on it.